# Is it possible to refresh a page through ajax in JSF?

Tags: ajax, jsf, refresh, page-refresh

I have something like this :

```
<h:commandButton action="#{MyBean.action()}">
   <f:ajax render ="@all"/>
</h:commandButton>
```

Is it possible to replace the "@all" in the ajax render to refresh the page?

Comment: @all refreshes the full page… or do you want a redirect?

Comment: With this code my page doesn't refresh like if I press F5

Comment: What DOES it do (from a developer perspective)

Answer (score 3):

> *With this code my page doesn't refresh like if I press F5*

That's not possible with ajax. Just remove `<f:ajax>` and send a redirect to self in action method.

```
<h:commandButton value="Submit and refresh" action="#{bean.action}" />
```

```
public String action() {
    // ...
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    return context.getViewRoot().getViewId() + "?faces-redirect=true";
}
```

Or if you actually don't need to perform a business action, just use `<h:button>` without an outcome.

```
<h:button value="Refresh only" />
```

Comment: Hmmm I never use `@all` but was realy under the impression that it was almost the same as doing a full redirect, ok with some downsides, but basic content could be refreshed… (I know viewscoped beans will be recreated in a full redirect and that that is one of the major differences, which makes it identical to pressing f5)

Comment: @Kukeltje: The only sensible real world use case for `@all` I encountered in my entire JSF career is showing an error page in its entirety like `FullAjaxExceptionHandler` does (it's under the covers using `PartialViewContext#setRenderAll()` for that).

Comment: :-) since I use omnifaces exceptionhandler, I had NO need to use `@all` in ANY way. Lucky me